# Matlab FRED data import (fetch error)

Tags: matlab, fetch

I always used matlab to get FRED data, but now I'm not able to get it anymore.
A simple code like:

```
c = fred('http://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/');
d = fetch(c,'DEXUSEU');
```

gets the error:
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

> Error in fred/fetch (line 93) d.Data =
>   [datenum(str2num(tmp(:,1:4)),str2num(tmp(:,6:7)),str2num(tmp(:,9:10)))
>   str2num(tmp(:,11:end))]; %#ok

Debugging the fetch function, the url it creates is ok, but in line 48 when it uses the urlread the result is:

> 301 Moved Permanently
>
> ## Moved 
>   Permanently
>
> The document has moved here.

Any suggestion?

Thank you

Comment: @David_Kelley Here is the same thing. The url works fine (download txt) but urlread don't work. Last week it worked fine. Don't you think its a FRED API error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that FRED doesn't like non-HTTPS requests. I get the same error you report in Matlab 2015a, but if you change the url to `https`, it works ok.

```
c = fred('https://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/');
d = fetch(c,'DEXUSEU');
```

If you take the url that Matlab is requesting from FRED and paste it in Chrome, you get a valid response (which I'm guessing Chrome is doing something to follow the link that the 301 error provides you while Matlab just gives up). They are still allowing non-HTTPS requests from their [API](https://api.stlouisfed.org/docs/fred/) service, but the base Matlab `fetch` function doesn't use the actual FRED API.

UPDATE: I just recieved the following email from FRED:

> FRED API requires HTTPS.
>
> Beginning on August 18, 2015, the FRED API will require HTTPS requests.  This change will help provide secure communication with the FRED API.  An automatic redirect will forward HTTP requests to HTTPS.  We recommend that you update the URLs in your code.  The API currently supports HTTPS to allow you to test your applications with this secure protocol.
>
> Please contact us at STLS.RSRCHWebmaster@stls.frb.org or 314-444-FRED (3733) if you have questions or concerns.  Thanks for using FRED and the FRED API.
>
> Sincerely,
>
> The FRED Team